# How do I record a variable in the same file that is open by command line multiple times?

Tags: c, variables, unix

I want to implement a bulletin board that only allows limited servers to connect. So I created a file server.c, and its executable file server.exe using gcc. I open two command line and both enter ./server consecutively. My question is how do I maintain a variable that could record how many servers have connected? Should I use static variable? Or should I use extern variables? Or if there are other ways?

```
//server.c

static int num_server_connect;

num_server_connect+=1;

fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", num_server_connect);
```

I've tried the above code by opening two command line to implement its executable file. But both of them print 1. What I expect is the first command line could show 1, and the second command line could show 2. And if the second command line leaves, I implement the first command line again, it could show 1.

Comment: You need to save it to the file.

Comment: Can you explain what "connect" means in this context? What specific platform are you running this on? Communication between processes will depend on that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm using select() or accept() function to receive connection from the clients. And I do this experiment on my local host. I'm running on wsl in windows system. So my experiment scenario is I would have client.c and server.c files, and I would open many wsl  to implement ./server with different ports to be like multi servers. However, there is a maximum amount of server that could connect to the bulletin board. So that's why I want to know how to maintain a variable that could let us know how many existed servers are open.

Comment: Although "server" can be used to mean a class of machines, it also can be used to mean the machine or program whose role is to accept connections and provide services to machines that connect.  It's unclear to me what your various uses of the word "server" are supposed to mean.  In particular "servers connect" is a pair of odd bedfellows. To a first approximations, servers do not connect to other machines -- rather, other machines connect *to them*.

Comment: Adding to John's comment, you may want to restructure how things are done. You may want a true network server. One that does `socket/bind/listen/accept`. You start a _single_ instance as a daemon. It will [easily] keep track of the number of connections. Then, clients do: `socket/connect` to that server. The server can count and restrict the number of connects. Generally, clients don't `fork/exec` separate instances of servers. But if two programs try to start separate instances of the server, it uses a file lock (e.g. `flock`) to ensure only one server is running at a time.